# Are there elements of order of order $4$ in the group $(\mathbb{Z}_{30}, +)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Are there elements of order of order $4$ in the group $(\mathbb{Z}_{30}, +)$? What is a way to approach this question without Lagrange's Theorem?

Comment: Well, in the absence of useful theorems, you could just compute the orders of all elements explicitly ...

Comment: If $x$ is of order $4$, then $30$ divides $4x$ which implies that $15$ divides $2x$. Since $15$ and $2$ are relatively prime, this means that $15$ divides $x$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose we had an element of order $4$, say $k$. This means $4k = 30n$ for some $n \in \Bbb Z^+$. Thus $2k$ is of order $2$.

Now finding elements of order $2$ is easier: since $0 \leq 2k < 30$, it follows that $2(2k) = 30n \implies n = 1$, since $0 \leq 4k < 60$.

So the only element of order $2$ is $15$. But: $15 \not\in \langle 2\rangle = \{0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22,24,26,28\} = 2\Bbb Z_{30}$.

Thus there is no $k$ with $2k = 15$, and $\Bbb Z_{30}$ has no element of (additive) order $4$.